# Custom post types imported from another wordpress site, not showing on frontend unless I go in and reupdate them

Tags: custom-post-types, import

I have duplicated a wordpress site, using the same theme and exported and imported same content. In the Wordpress admin everything seems there in the new site after the import, but when I go to pages which should show those post types, they are empty. Also all the custom post types showed as "Published" I went into each of them and hit update button and now they show. But have no idea why this could be or how to prevent it for future imports.

Comment: And the same plugins? Specifically whichever plugin registers those custom post types? (Or maybe theme too, but I'm not 100% they can supply post types)

Comment: My theme registers them, also everything works when I make local duplicates of my site and import the same content with the same theme. I suspect it's related to the Import process, but wasn't able to point to one exact reason.